# Error: Space manager is invalid

Tags: hard-drive, safari, mail.app, disk-utility, hardware

My macbook (Mid-2012, Non-retina) crashed today and it beeped. I managed to solve it by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXYpUxS04oc). Actually it did not solve. So i upgrade to Majove from Sierra. This way, my macbook start to boot. However, Safari and Mail apps won't open and when i try to "First Aid" on Disk Utility, it gave me

> "error: spaceman chunk disk address out of order: 0x2600080, expected
>   0x2600000  Space manager is invalid.

What should i do?

Thank you very much